# Make a <td> rendered by Javascript clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm quite new to webdevelopment and AJAX and I'm facing a little issue there. Basically, I have a form on my webpage. When I submit this form, it makes an AJAX call to my controller, send me the data I want back, and change the html content of the page.

JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#mydiv table tbody td").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked my <td>!" + $(this).html() + 
              "My TR is:" + $(this).parent("tr").html());
    });



    $('#myform').submit(function()
    {
        try {
            var host = $("#host").val();
            var port = $("#port").val();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var database = $("#database").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/management/connectDatabase",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: "host="+host+"&port="+port+"&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&database="+database,
                cache: false,
                success: 
                    function(data){
                        $('#mydiv').html(show_tables(data));
                    },
            });
            return false;
        }

        catch(e){
            console.debug(e);
        }
    });
});

function show_tables(data)
{
    var html = '<div id="mydiv">';

    html += '<table class="display" id="example">';
    html += '<thead><tr><th>Tables</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    for (var tablesCount = 0; tablesCount < data.tables.length; tablesCount++){
        html += '<tr class=gradeA id="trtest">';
        html += '<td id="tdtest">' + data.tables[tablesCount] + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += '</tbody></table>';

    html += '</div>';
    return html;
}
```

When I submit the form, the HTML is generating right, and I can see my content. But, I can't click on any entries of the `<table>`. Moreover, when I want to see the sourcecode of my page, it doesn't displays me the table, but still my form, even if it has still been validated.

Could someone explain me what I do wrong here ?

Comment: The view source option of your browser shows the code as it was downloaded. Use built-in developer tools (F12 in IE / Chrome and I believe Safari too; Ctrl + Shift +I in Opera) or, if you're using Firefox I'd recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) (F12 key too) to view and edit the rendered [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM).

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if you prefer to view the HTML source of the document as it is currently rendered (which may come in handy sometimes), I'd recommend [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which jQuery version you're using, you need to either bind the click event using `jQuery.delegate` or `jQuery.on` in order for things to work with dynamically added DOM elements.

Edit: as pointed out by Geert Jaminon, you have to use the `selector` parameter of the `on` function. This works for me.

```
$("#mydiv table tbody").on('click', 'td', function() {
    alert("You clicked my <td>!" + $(this).html() + 
          "My TR is:" + $(this).parent("tr").html());
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work in my case. I changed the part of code concerned to fit what you tell me, and the behaviour remains the same apparently.

Comment: try using `.live` instead of `.on`, it has the same makeup

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use ?

Comment: @Luuky19 `.live` is working, thanks !
@ManuLetroll I'm using jQuery v.1.7.2

Comment: @Luuky19 As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: @Geert Jaminon I know, but I tested both in jsfiddel and `.live` worked and `.on` didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mydiv table tbody").on('click', 'td', function() {
    alert("You clicked my <td>!" + $(this).html() + "My TR is:" + $(this).parent("tr").html());
});
```

.live() is replaced by .on() in the newer jQuery versions.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqYgv/

Answer (score 0):

If you insert data dynamically, you need to add the click event after the data has been inserted.

http://codepen.io/thomassnielsen/pen/FEKDg

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  // Add .click code here
});
```

Comment: But in my case, as the code that generates the html content is in an ajax call, I don't really know how to make it.

Comment: Just call the .click() function in the ajax call return function (updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the click event handler after the rendering of the elements, since they weren't in place when you made the binding.